# First attempts with MySQL prepared statements

Tags: php, mysql

I'm fighting with some php code for retrieving data from a db using prepared statements.
Before using such statements I used to fetch all data I needed with the mysqli_fetch_assoc function.
Now I have this code and it won't work..
($dbc is the link to the db)

```
$q = "SELECT name, surname FROM users WHERE employee_number = ?"
$stmt = mysqli_prepare($dbc, $q);

mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, 's', $employee_number);
mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
mysqli_stmt_store_result($stmt);

$count = mysqli_stmt_num_rows($stmt);

if ($count == 1)
{
mysqli_stmt_bind_result($stmt, $employee_number);
session_start();

while (mysqli_stmt_fetch($stmt))
{
$_SESSION['emp'] = $employee_number;
}
}
```

This is a shortened version of course.
The fact is that it does not work at all.
Do I make any logical mistakes?
It is my first day with prepared statements and functions related to them.

Comment: `it does not work` isn't very helpful. Do you get errors? Do you get an empty resultset? Session is not populated?

Comment: And by does not work at all you mean what? Is it crashing? Giving you errors? Not displaying _what you expected_ (what did you expect)?

Comment: there are a million ways in which it could be not working, perhaps it causes the  neighbours bog to bark

Comment: I've heard of barking dogs, but it's a long time since I saw a barking bog :) Reminds me of the crows' song from Dumbo http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=s35puUhqQJc

Comment: You don't actually SELECT the employee number from the table...

Comment: @Jon So? You select the columns you want in the resultset, it being used as a filter has nothing to do with it being selected or not. The query is fine, provided the column names are right and the table exists, which we don't know

Comment: dog trapped in bog? dyslexia strikes gaina !

Comment: @DamienPirsy Sorry, I wasn't clear. Binding the columns in the result set to `$employee_number` in this line `mysqli_stmt_bind_result($stmt, $employee_number)` and then storing that value in the `$_SESSION` made me wonder whether the query was wrong. Additionally, you must bind all columns from the result set to variables, which this code does not do.